# Error upgrading postgresql cluster from 9.1 to 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on Amazon EC2.
Trying to upgrade postgresql from 9.1 to 9.2.

```
$ uname -a
Linux db2 3.2.0-32-virtual #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:53:42 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt-cache policy postgresql
postgresql:
  Installed: 9.1+136~precise
  Candidate: 9.1+136~precise
  Version table:
 *** 9.1+136~precise 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64                 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 9.1+129ubuntu1 0
    500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
 9.1+129 0
    500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

The upgrade process I'm following is:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgres-9.2
$ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.2 main
$ sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.1 main /var/lib/postgresql/9.2
Stopping old cluster...
Disabling connections to the old cluster during upgrade...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Creating new cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/9.2/main, data: /var/lib/postgresql/9.2)...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/postgresql.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.2/main...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/pg_hba.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.2/main...
Moving configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/pg_ident.conf to /etc/postgresql/9.2/main...
Configuring postgresql.conf to use port 5433...
Disabling connections to the new cluster during upgrade...
Roles, databases, schemas, ACLs...
Fixing hardcoded library paths for stored procedures...
ERROR:  cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery
Error: Could not fix library paths
Re-enabling connections to the old cluster...
Re-enabling connections to the new cluster...
Error during cluster dumping, removing new cluster
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: That's an odd one, looks like a `pg_upgrade` issue. I'd suggest asking on the [pgsql-general mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/) if you don't get any response here. Any chance you can find out the actual `pg_upgrade` command line - from `ps` say?

Comment: @CraigRinger: pg_upgradecluster is a Perl script. https://gist.github.com/3909063 I may step into it. Thanks for the mailing list suggestion.

Comment: That appears to be `pg_upgradecluster`, part of `pg_wrapper`. The command that does the actual work is called `pg_upgrade`. It is a C program distributed with PostgreSQL. `pg_upgradecluster` should be calling `pg_upgrade` but it looks like it might be failing before it gets to that point.

Comment: Line 421 looks like your error point. The error `ERROR:  cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery` from Pg suggests that it's running in hot standby mode, which seems odd. Is `hot_standby` set to `on` in `postgresql.conf` on the old cluster? See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html

Comment: Oooh, hang on. `pg_wrapper`'s upgrade script doesn't use `pg_upgrade` at all, it looks like it's just doing a dump and reload for you.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Ouch! You're right. The 9.1 instance is a replication slave. Duh. Sorry and thanks again. Will reconfigure and post back here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is that `hot_standby` is `on` in `postgresql.conf`, so the server is read-only.

In general, if you're having issues with `pg_upgradecluster` from the `pg_wrapper` tools typically packaged in Debian and Ubuntu you can do a manual cluster upgrade instead:

- Start the old server
- `sudo -i -u postgres`
- `for db in $(psql --tuples-only template1 -c "select datname from pg_database where datname not in ('template0','template1','postgres','template_postgis');"); do pg_dump -Fc -f $db.backup $db; done`
- `pg_dumpall --globals-only > globals.sql`
- Stop the old server
- `initdb` a new cluster on the new server if you've removed it. With `pg_wrapper` I think you use `pg_createcluster` for this.
- Start the new server; and still as the `postgres` user:
- `psql -f globals.sql`
- `for backup in *.backup; do pg_restore --dbname postgres --create $backup; done`

Alternately, use the `pg_upgrade` tool tool to in-place convert your DB, but that might confuse `pg_wrapper`.

These steps can be simplified by using the `pg_dumpall` command to make a whole cluster dump, but I don't like it much. I think restoring `pg_dumpall` dumps leaves much to be desired in terms of error handling, it's hard to extract individual DBs or tables from the dump, and it can't all be restored in a single transaction. I strongly prefer using `pg_dumpall` only for globals like users/groups/roles, and `pg_dump` per-database custom-format backups for individual databases as shown above.

Comment: Or take the server out of hot_standby. Like you suspected. (Now sneaking back out of room...)

Answer (score 1):

General steps for upgrading if you [installed from apt](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

In my case from pg11 to pg12:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-12
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main #stop the autocreated/autostarted one
pg_dropcluster 12 main # drop it
sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster -v 12 11 main

sudo systemctl start postgresql@12-main
sudo -u postgres psql <yourdb> # up and test it
```